# How many parameters are in CNN filters?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

How many parameters are in each filter for a convolutional neural network?
My book says:

> "In color images, every filter is itself a 3D filter. This means every filter has a number of parameters: `(height x width x depth) = (3 x 3 x 3 = 27)`. You can see how the network complexity increases when processing color images because it has to optimize more parameters..."

This makes it sound like say a `2 X 2` filter would actually be `2 X 2 X 3`, for color images. However, the parameter feature in Keras seems to count the filter as 3D the first time, but only 2D for subsequent times.

Here is my output data:

| Layer (type) | Output Shape | Param # |
| --- | --- | --- |
| conv2d (Conv2D) | (None, 32, 32, 16) | 208 |
| max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) | (None, 16, 16, 16) | 0 |
| conv2d_1 (Conv2D) | (None, 16, 16, 32) | 2080 |
| max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 | (None, 8, 8, 32) | 0 |
| conv2d_2 (Conv2D) | (None, 8, 8, 64) | 8256 |
| max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 | (None, 4, 4, 64) | 0 |

So in the first example, I have `16 parameters x (2 x 2 x 3 filter) x 1 depth` of `previous layer + 16 biases = 208`. So in this example, the filter IS counted as a 3D filter, since there can be different values for each of the three color channels.

However, if you look at the next value, we have `32 parameters x (2 x 2 x 3 filter) x 16 depth of previous layer + 32 biases = 6176`. The only way I can get `2080` is if I omit the 3 in the filter.

The same thing happens with the last convolutional layer that I have, as well.
I have `64 parameters x (2 x 2 x 3 filter) x 32 depth of previous layer + 64 biases`, which should equal `24,640`, but instead only equals `8256`, which is about 1/3 the value of what it should be (the only reason it isn't exactly a third is because there are still 64 biases).

Why is this happening? I can't understand why you wouldn't have 3 channels for each of the filters, because otherwise the filters aren't color filters anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In convolutions, when they mean that filters are (height x width x depth) shaped, the "depth" refers to the number of channels from the previous input, which isn't necessarily an RGB image (it could be from a previous convolution).

For how the second convolution has 2080 parameters instead of 6176, the input depth is actually 16 channels instead of three because your first convolution increased the number of channels to 16, so the correct calculation would be (2 * 2 * 16 * 32) + 32 which equals 2080.

Likewise, for your third convolution, since its input has 32 channels from the output of the second convolution, its number of parameters would be equal to (2 * 2 * 32 * 64) + 64 which equals 8256 parameters.